# How can I perform mutation testing of my Java program?

Tags: java, testing, mutation-testing

Can anyone provide suggestions of tools that can be used to make mutations within a Java program at a source-code (not byte-code) level? I need to seed my source code with faults. I would prefer an application with a GUI, if one exists.

Comment: This has little application in the real world

Comment: Simply replacing some random characters by others could do, but in most cases this will be letal (i.e. the resulting program will not be compilable, if you did't hit a string or comment or replaced really luckily).

Comment: "This has little application in the real world" is a poor excuse. When tensor, topology or calculus mathematics were developed, they had very "little real world use". This is an interesting question. Code mutation has very real world applications.

Comment: It might be useful if you could provide suggestions (i.e. examples) of mutations you would like and the attributes of the result - should it still compile, should the errors be regularly placed, etc.

Comment: @Bohemian:  It is applied in the real world for determining test coverage.

Comment: How is this question too localized? Mutant (or mutation) testing is a valid testing technique that can be used to test software applications. However, it's not commonly used since it's time-intensive (and therefore, for most projects, cost-intensive as well).

Comment: https://pitest.org is the number 1 Mutation Testing tool for Java today (2023), but this is done at _byte code_ level rather than _source code_ level

Answer (score 4):

I've found https://pitest.org, which I quite like. With MuJava I have exceptions caused by @Override annotations. Seems that it doesnt' support Java 5/6.

Comment: Good overview of PIT here: http://dev.theladders.com/2013/02/mutation-testing-with-pit-a-step-beyond-normal-code-coverage/

Comment: Broken link above. Baeldung have a recent article (2022) https://www.baeldung.com/java-mutation-testing-with-pitest

Answer (score 4):

If your requirement really is for source code mutation then the options I'm aware of are

Jester - Provides a limited number of mutation operators that are quite unstable. Jeff Offutt described it as a very expensive way to apply branch testing. I believe it is possible to define your own operators however, so this probably isn't entirely fair.

Mu Java - Doesn't support Java 5

Judy - Don't know much about this other than that it exists

Lava - Sounds pretty basic and I don't think it supports java 5

From the answer further down I see your now using PIT. I think that's a truly great choice (I wrote it so may have a certain bias), but it's a byte code mutation system.

Answer (score 3):

When I took a software engineering class on testing at GMU, [we used Mu Java](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/mujava/), for one of the chapters.  HTH

Comment: Thanks! I also tried it, but it doesn't work for me. @Override annotation is causing exceptions..

Comment: Since 2016, it appears muJava is now abandonware: https://github.com/jeffoffutt/muJava

Answer (score 3):

This is the technique used by the open source test coverage tool [Jester](http://jester.sourceforge.net/).  A look at it's source might be helpful if you are unable to find a suitable tool and want to build one yourself.

Comment: Since 2009, it appears Jester is now abandonware: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jester/files

Answer (score 2):

"This has little application in the real world". Disagree strongly, I contract at a very big media company in the UK and PIT (http://pitest.org/) is extremely useful for mutation testing. Most of the CI builds are set fail without 85% coverage PIT mutation testing.
Re: "replacing some random characters..." Mutation does not have to mean that. The PIT mutations are restricted to compilable changes.

Comment: How do you deal with equivalent mutations if you require a 100% mutation coverage?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a benchmark :

MμClipse only supports JUnit 3 and is no longer maintained. 
Jester as for it, is laborious and requires a complicated configuration; plus is not maintained anymore.
The best tool I could find is Javalanche
[I had wrote a entire article about this !](http://blog.octo.com/en/mutation-testing-a-step-further-to-the-perfection/)

Comment: Since 2013, it appears MuClipse is now abandonware: https://sourceforge.net/projects/muclipse (MuClipse was an Eclipse plugin wrapper for MuJava, which itself became abandonware in 2016)

Answer (score 1):

The Major mutation framework ([Major's website](http://mutation-testing.org)) provides a compiler-integrated mutator and a mutation analyzer for JUnit tests.

Major's mutator is integrated in the Java 7 compiler. It provides several mutation operators and supports two options for mutating source code:

1. Generate and embed all mutants during compilation
2. Generate mutants and export mutated source files