# Tools for mutation testing

Tags: testing

On our company, we want to start to evaluate a quality of unit tests by creating mutation on our code.

Does anyone know any tool for mutation testing that uses Maven and can be integrated into the hudson?

Comment: PIT clearly! have a look at my intro on MT/PIT https://pedrorijo.com/blog/intro-mutation/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java is your language of choice, [PIT](http://pitest.org/) is a good tool. I also suggest you read this article [Mutation Testing, a step further to the perfection](http://blog.octo.com/en/mutation-testing-a-step-further-to-the-perfection/)

This thread compares other available tools: [How can I perform mutation testing of my Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487784/how-can-i-perform-mutation-testing-of-my-java-program)

Comment: The PIT I know. Any another tool?

Answer (score 1):

PIT it the only tool I'm aware of that provides a maven plugin.

A summary of some of the other options is available here

http://pitest.org/java_mutation_testing_systems/